# SQL: Finding duplicate records based on custom criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find duplicates based on two tables and based on custom criteria. The following determines whether it's a duplicate, and if so, show only the most recent one:

If Employee Name and all EmployeePolicy CoverageId(s) are an exact match another record, then that's considered a duplicate.

```
--Employee Table
EmployeeId  Name  Salary
543         John  54000
785         Alex  63000
435         John  75000
123         Alex  88000
333         John  67000

--EmployeePolicy Table
EmployeePolicyId  EmployeeId  CoverageId
1                 543         8888
2                 543         7777
3                 785         5555
4                 435         8888
5                 435         7777
6                 123         4444
7                 333         8888
8                 333         7776
```

For example, the duplicates in the example above are the following:

```
EmployeeId Name Salary
543        John 54000
435        John 75000
```

This is because they are the only ones that have a matching name in the Employee table as well as both have the same exact CoverageIds in the EmployeePolicy table.

**Note:** EmployeeId 333 also with Name = John is not a match because both of his CoverageIDs are not the same as the other John's CoverageIds.

At first I have been trying to find duplicates the old fashioned way by Grouping records and saying having count(*) > 1, but then quickly realized that it would not work because while in English my criteria defines a duplicate, in SQL the CoverageIDs are different so they are NOT considered duplicates.

By that same accord, I tried something like:

```
-- Create a TMP table

INSERT INTO #tmp
SELECT *
FROM Employee e join EmployeePolicy ep on e.EmpoyeeId = ep.EmployeeId

SELECT info.* 
FROM  
(
    SELECT 
        tmp.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tmp.Name, tmp.CoverageId ORDER BY tmp.EmployeeId DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM #tmp tmp  
) info  
WHERE 
    info.RowNum = 1 AND
```

Again, this does not work because SQL does not see this as duplicates. Not sure how to translate my English definition of duplicate into SQL definition of duplicate.

Any help is most appreciated.

Comment: Fill temp tables with sample data and show expected result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to concatenate the policies into a string.  That, alas, is cumbersome in SQL Server.  Here is a set-based approach:

```
with ep as (
      select ep.*, count(*) over (partition by employeeid) as cnt
      from employeepolicy ep
     )
select ep.employeeid, ep2.employeeid
from ep join
     ep ep2
     on ep.employeeid < ep2.employeeid and
        ep.CoverageId = ep2.CoverageId and
        ep.cnt = ep2.cnt
group by ep.employeeid, ep2.employeeid, ep.cnt
having count(*) = cnt   -- all match
```

The idea is to match the coverages for different employees.  A simple criteria is that the number of coverages need to match.  Then, it checks that the number of matching coverages is the actual count.

Note:  This puts the employee id pairs in a single row.  You can join back to the employees table to get the additional information.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested the T-SQL but I believe the following should give you the output you are looking for.

```
;WITH CTE_Employee
AS
(
    SELECT       E.[Name]
                ,E.[EmployeeId]
                ,P.[CoverageId]
                ,E.[Salary]
    FROM        Employee E
    INNER JOIN  EmployeePolicy P ON E.EmployeeId = P.EmployeeId
)
, CTE_DuplicateCoverage
AS
(
    SELECT       E.[Name]
                ,E.[CoverageId]
    FROM        CTE_Employee E
    GROUP BY    E.[Name], E.[CoverageId]
    HAVING      COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT      E.[EmployeeId]
            ,E.[Name]
            ,MAX(E.[Salary]) AS [Salary]
FROM        CTE_Employee E
INNER JOIN  CTE_DuplicateCoverage D ON E.[Name] = D.[Name] AND E.[CoverageId] = D.[CoverageId]
GROUP BY    E.[EmployeeId], E.[Name]
HAVING      COUNT(*) > 1
ORDER BY    E.[EmployeeId]
```